# C# JSON Deserialization Dictionary Exception

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I need help with JSON parsing in C#. There is my JSON string I am trying to parse and to work with. I do not want to create a class to instantiate the object, because there can be more calls with a lot of returning object type - Tournament, Team, User, etc.

```
{
    "response":{
        "2":{
            "tournament_id":2,
            "created_at":{
                "date":"2015-11-09 21:01:06",
                "timezone_type":3,
                "timezone":"Europe/Prague"
            },
            "creator_id":1,
            "name":"Tournament Test #1",
            "desc":"...!",
            "state":0,
            "is_visible":1
        },
        "3":{
            "tournament_id":3,
            "created_at":{
                "date":"2015-11-09 21:01:06",
                "timezone_type":3,
                "timezone":"Europe/Prague"
            },
            "creator_id":1,
            "name":"Tournament Test #2",
            "desc":"...",
            "state":1,
            "is_visible":1
        }
    },
    "error":false
}
```

I am using JSON.net library to parse JSON string and this is C# code I am using in my program:

```
public class API
    {
        private WebClient client;

        protected string auth_key   = "xxx";
        protected string base_url   = "http://127.0.0.1/tournaments_api/www/";
        private string endpoint_url = "";
        private string url_params   = "";

        public string url_data;
        public Dictionary<string, string>[] data;

        public bool success = false;
        public string errorMessage = "";
        public int errorCode = 0;

        public API()
        {
            this.client = new WebClient();
        }

        private void Request()
        {

            string url = this.base_url + this.endpoint_url + "/" + this.auth_key + "?" + this.url_params;
            this.url_data = this.client.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine(this.url_data);

            this.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(this.url_data);
        }
    }
```

There is this problem with parsing:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String][]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'response', line 1, position 12.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You have absolutely no arrays in your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an object, which in C# can be deserialized as `Dictionary<string, object>`. However, you try to deserialize it as an array, while there are absolutely no arrays.

You need to change this to:

```
public Dictionary<string, object>[] data;

// ...

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(this.url_data);
```

At the same time, even after changing it, you won't be able to access the nested objects.

As you write that

> I do not want to create a class to instantiate the object, because there can be more calls with a lot of returning object type - Tournament, Team, User, etc.

I may suggest to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(this.url_data);
```

Then, you will be able to work with it like with dynamic object:

```
var err = data.error;
```

At the same time, creating a classes to describe this model and to be used for deserializing this JSON sounds better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's answer is to use the built-in LINQ to JSON support of the JSON.NET library:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse("-- JSON STRING --");

JToken response = jObject["response"];

bool error = jObject["error"].Value<bool>();
```

There are a lot of extensions methods that allow easy parsing of json strings.